# Why does jQuery Datepicker fail to change dateformat?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-datepicker

All:

Here are the jquery versions that I'm using:

1. jquery 2.1.4
2. jquery-UI 1.11.2

In my ASPX web page, I have the following:

```
     Start Date: <input type="text" id="startdate" size="30"/>    
  End Date: <input type="text" id="enddate" size="30"/>




<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function () {     
        $("#startdate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd' });
        $("#enddate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd' });
    });
</script>
```

However, the startdate and enddate still goes back to the standard format of mm/dd/yyyy default format.

Why does the  format fail to change when the dateFormat is specified?  Also, how could I fix the problem?

Comment: Try writing it like this and check : `$("#startdate").datepicker({ format: 'yyyy-mm-dd', autoclose : true });`

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked.  But I can't figure out why my Original Post Code failed to work because so many stackoverflow[dot]com answers stated that it will work.

Comment: Probably this might be due the keyword that is used for **format** in different versions of JQuery. But then again, I find it tricky when **dateFormat** keyword doesn't work and **format** works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @matt-Murdock

Your suggestion worked.

```
      $("#startdate").datepicker({
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd', autoclose: true
        });
        $("#enddate").datepicker({
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd', autoclose: true
        });
```

However, I'm still confused as to why specifying the way I did in the Original Post failed to work.  Almost all the other similar questions on the internet stated that the way I posted it in my Original Post worked.  Is it because of the jquery versions that I'm using?

1.jquery 2.1.4

2.jquery-UI 1.11.2

Answer (score 1):

For jquery datepicker, year format should be either y (2 digit) or yy ( 4 digit). So, you may try "yy-mm-dd" for your purpose.

See details here: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate

Answer (score 1):

Try following, your format is not correct.

```
        $( "#startdate" ).datepicker({                          
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
        });
```

Comment: Already tried it, It's strange that it failed to work.  A lot of Stackoverflow posts suggest to try it your way, and they were accepted as the correct answer.  But it failed to work for me.  Is it because of my jquery versions that I'm using:
----jquery 2.1.4 
----jquery-UI 1.11.2

Comment: Thx for following up.  @matt-Murdock provided the solution.  However, I'm a little frustrated that using dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" failed to work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the dateformat in your datepicker.jquery.js than only it will replicate to your view.

Answer (score 1):

try using like this:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd" );
```

Comment: Thx for following up.  @matt-Murdock provided the solution.  However, I'm a little frustrated that using dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" failed to work.